# Azure doesn't get id of the row

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I got all Items from Azure Table but it didn't give the id of the row
Here method where i get all items.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
              final List<Hyip> results = mTable.execute().get();
              activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      eAdapter.clear();
                      try {
                          for (Hyip item : results) {
                                  eAdapter.add(item);
                          }
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      } finally {
                          eAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          ((MainActivity)context).isDone = true;
                      }
                  }
              });
          } catch (Exception exception) {
              exception.printStackTrace();
              exception.getCause();
          }
          return null;
      }
}
```

How can i get the row id? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding for your code, it seems that you got the items from Mobile Service Table using Android client SDK, not Azure Table Storage.

So I suggest that you can try to refer to the offical tutorial [How to use the Android client library for Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/) to know how to use it.

If you use Azure Table Storage, as @Steven said, it's NoSQL store service, there is no id column default in the table. But you can try to define an id property for an entity with a custom unique identify like UUID or GUID for querying.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table storage is a service that stores structured NoSQL data in the cloud, an entity's partition and row key uniquely identify the entity in the table.

So if you use Azure Table Storage there is no id column in the table. Check out [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) for more details.